# Why won't string change to date using cast or convert?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a very basic query

The data is separated like this `MM/DD/YYYY`.

I've tried casting and converting both result in the same error.

```
SELECT CAST(Workorder.ArrivalDate AS date) FROM WorkOrders
```

Error I get:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Because SQL Server doesn't know if your string is MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CONVERT()` with an explicit format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, Workorder.ArrivalDate, 101)
FROM JobWorkOrders;
```

If you still have a problem, find the offending values using `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT Workorder.ArrivalDate
FROM JobWorkOrders
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, Workorder.ArrivalDate, 101) IS NULL;
```

Then, start working on fixing the data so dates are stored as `DATE`s and not as strings.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. It still results in the same error.

Comment: I am using TSQL 2008, so I end up with the same error including this Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with the Data set and I did not do enough to vet it correctly. 
I had to eliminate all string values like text that users were entering into the table.

So basically what I did was the following:

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, Workorder.ArrivalDate, 101)
FROM WorkOrders
WHERE ArrivalDate NOT IN ('3/1/16','6-30-13','8-9-12','9-10-2013','At ITM','here','In','in house','n','N/A','NA','NB EC','new build','TBD')

If there is a better way to do this I am open to hearing it!

Comment: "If there is a better way to do this I am open to hearing it!" Change the database field to a date field and change the input process to use a date value instead of a string (I'm assuming this will be difficult, but it is the best solution)